# Add CSS class to HTML with Javascript ternary operator

Tags: javascript, css, conditional-operator

I need to add a checkmark image from the css class `.checkmark` or `.stem` but don´t know how to add it.
I have tried different solutions but I only get errors or just a `string`. The image checkmark should be added to the ternary operator where it says `checkmark`.

```
import {
    myArray
} from './theData.js';

function addCheckmark() {
    let checkmark = document.getElementsByClassName(".checkmark");
    let stem = document.getElementsByClassName(".stem");
    checkmark.appendChild(stem)
}

buildTable(myArray);

function buildTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let row = `<tr>
    <td>${data[i].gameNumber}</td>
    <td>${data[i].teams["1"].name} -VS- ${data[i].teams["2"].name}</td>
    <td>${data[i].outcome === "1" ? "checkmark":  ""}</td>
    <td>${data[i].outcome === "X" ? "checkmark" : ""}</td>
    <td>${data[i].outcome === "2" ? "checkmark" : ""}</td>

    </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is a collection/nodeList and is array-like

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output from that input? Click edit, then change your import statement to the actual array and create a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: So, instead of `"checkmark"`, write `"<img src='path/to/checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>"` or whatever HTML you need...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this line:

`let checkmark = document.getElementsByClassName(".checkmark");`

1. It should be "checkmark", not ".checkmark" because that's the class name.
2. `getElementsByClassName` is a collection (similar to an array) and should be treated as such.
3. Use `const` instead of `let` for values that are never changed.

This code adds a checkmark to ALL items:

```
function addCheckmark() {
  const checkmarks = document.querySelectorAll('.checkmark');
  const stem = document.querySelector('.stem');
  checkmarks.forEach(checkmark => checkmark.appendChild(stem));
}
```

> The answers you will get here might not solve your issue because your question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks! 
I am supposed to publish a checkmark from the css into the td:s. It is a result table for football matches. So where it now says "checkmark" in the ternary I am supposed to get the checkmark from the css. But I just get errors...  what should I put there?
Hope this clarifies the question...

Comment: @SvenE which errors do you get? Let's start there..